# spring amqp (rabbitmq) and sending to DLQ when exception occurs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:2.6.6 .
According to the documentation, I set up `@RabbitListener` - I use `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` and the configuration looks like this:

```java
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ObjectMapper om) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(rabbitProperties.getUpdater().getConcurrentConsumers());
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(rabbitProperties.getUpdater().getMaxConcurrentConsumers());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(om));
        factory.setAutoStartup(rabbitProperties.getUpdater().getAutoStartup());
        factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        return factory;
    }
```

The logic of the service is to receive messages from rabbitmq, contact an external service via the rest API (using rest template) and put some information into the database based on the results of the response (using spring data jpa). The service implemented it successfully, but during testing it ran into problems that if any exceptions occur during the work of those thrown up the stack, the message is not sent to the configured dlq, but simply hangs in the broker as unacked. Can you please tell me how you can tell spring amqp that if any error occurs, you need to redirect the message to dlq?

The listener itself looks something like this:

```java
    @RabbitListener(
            queues = {"${rabbit.updater.consuming.queue.name}"},
            containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    @Override
    public void listen(
            @Valid @Payload MessageDTO message,
            Channel channel,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag
    ) {

        log.debug(DebugMessagesConstants.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_FROM_QUEUE, message, deliveryTag);

        messageUpdater.process(message);
        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);

        log.debug(DebugMessagesConstants.PROCESSED_MESSAGE_FROM_QUEUE, message, deliveryTag);

    }
```

In rabbit managment it look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0LgF.png)
and unacked will hang until the queue consuming application stops

Answer (score 1):

See error handling documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling.

So, you just don't do an `AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL` and rely on the Dead Letter Exchange configuration for those messages which are rejected in case of error.

Or try to use a `this.channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, false)` in case of  `messageUpdater.process(message);` exception...